# How to stop AWS WAF being bypassed by accessing Elastic Beanstalk instance directly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have currently got an Elastic Beanstalk web app within a VPC which I'd like to put behind a WAF.  In order to do this I've added CloudFront with the WAF looking at that. For security I've enabled access to the Elastic Beanstalk app only from the AWS CloudFront IP addresses, which I have done using security groups (auto updating when these IP addresses change).

However, what is to stop someone else adding my EB app web address to their own CloudFront instance, would this bypass my IP address limitations on the VPC security group and give them access without going through my WAF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what might help here is to add some secret custom header in your CloudFront distribution (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/forward-custom-headers.html), and make your origin check for the presence of the header. This will ensure that only your distribution can get data from your origin server.

Comment: Can't people just inject the custom header manually if they were to be forging request to be sent directly to the web server?

Comment: This solution assumes that the header is not known (which is the case for external attacker). To know the header attacker would need to either be able to access CloudFront's distribution configuration, or to EB configuration.

Comment: Goes without saying then that SSL is also required.